# SKSpriteNode Collision not working as expected

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm creating a pinball game and detect collision between the ball and the bumpers. This code works most of the time, but there are some times when the ball travels through the bumper. I have a print statement that registers that the ball hit the bumper, but the impulse to the ball is not delivered.

Here is the code that is fired when the collision happens:

```
func handleBallAndTargetCollision( _ theBall:Ball, target:Target, contactPoint:CGPoint) {
    if target.isBumper {
        print("Collided with bumper: \(target.name)")
        let xDiff:CGFloat =  contactPoint.x - target.position.x
        let yDiff:CGFloat =  contactPoint.y - target.position.y
        let theForce:CGVector = CGVector(dx: xDiff * target.impactForce, dy: yDiff * target.impactForce)
        theBall.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(theForce )
    } else {
        handleTarget(target: target)
    }
}
```

This code should shoot the ball in the opposite direction from where it hit the bumper.

Is there a better way to do this besides applying an impulse to the ball?

Any reason why the ball would sometimes travel through the bumper without the impulse being applied?

Comment: Why are you applying the force to the ball?  You apply the force to the bumper, and let the physics do the rest

Comment: if your xDiff and yDiff is 0, then no force is applied, you could also be applying the force in the wrong direction

Comment: Knight0fDragon - Regarding adding force to the bumper, I'm not sure how that would work. Is there an example you can point me to? I checked the xDiff and yDiff for being zero, that never happened in my tests. I will investigate further to see if it is getting sent in the wrong direction in some cases.